# Easeljs Big Canvas FPS drop

Tags: javascript, performance, animation, frame-rate, easeljs

I manipulate a 1024x768 canvas with easeljs.

```
 <canvas id="testcanvas" height="768" width="1024"></canvas>
```

Take a look at this fiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/2TPHg/

Enlarge the html window and drag the rectangle, look at the console, see the fps dropping to 40 in my application it drops to 20 how can i improve it to 60

Answer (score 0):

Well, you had a null reference to the stage, and it wasn't updating correctly.

Since the stage is a global variable, you don't need to find it (unless you have multiple stage objects).

You can update the stage on the ticker event listener function, and do so only when the ticker is not paused.

pause and un-pause via the user interaction with the mouse:

http://jsfiddle.net/2TPHg/4/

```
createjs.Ticker.addEventListener("tick", function(e) {
    if(e.paused !== true){
        stage.update();
        txt.innerHTML = createjs.Ticker.getMeasuredFPS();
    }
});
```

I was able to get a solid 60 fps with this.
Keep in mind that even tracing to the console will take CPU cycles, and may slow down slower computers even if only by a little.

Comment: did you enlarge the html, i still get about 30 fps even worse than before.

Comment: Even in your example, with changing nothing but the canvas size (2000px by 2000px), and still referencing the null stage, and tracing to the console, I get 60fps on my machine (mac book pro).